# Android - Make Toast from static method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, static, toast

I'm trying to pass a string from a separate static java class, to a method inside my Blankfragment.java

this is the method inside the blankFragment.java, the problem is that it can't access getContext() which is non static.

```
public static void ShowMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getContext() ,message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And the method call in the **separate** **static** java class:

```
BlankFragment.ShowMessage(new String(body));
```

Is there a way to retrieve the context from outside and pass it as a parameter? getContext() does not work, I get the error "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: Yes. Structure your param as `showMessage(String message, Context context)`. When calling the method, `.showMessage(new String(body), getApplicationContext())`. For fragment, use `getContext()`

Answer (score 5):

You could try pass the context as a parameter. Since this is a Fragment, I do recommend you check for nulls!

```
public static void ShowMessage(Context context, String message){
    if (context == null) return;
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

BlankFragment.ShowMessage(getContext(), new String(body));
```

*NOTE:*

I have **just** been working with Fragments and I absolutely HATE their lifecycle. I am not entirely sure why you need a static method involving context but I recommend against it. Rather use a [Command pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm) or something else. Normally I find that until the Fragment has "settled down" - then the context becomes available.

Comment: The following call: BlankFragment.ShowMessage(getContext(), new String(body)); Will be called from a separate javaclass, so I don't have access to that method from there, I simply get the error "cant resolve symbol"

Comment: If you are using method in a Fragment class, try checking my answer...you should be able to reach Activity within Fragment class.

Comment: The class I am calling BlankFragment.ShowMessage(getContext(), new String(body)); from is a static java class implementing the rabbitmq defaultconsumer interface. its not a fragment or an activity

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this Method (or calling it from) a Fragment, then fragment has access to Activity with `getActivity();` . Pass it as parameter.

But if you are actually using the method within the Fragment (the displaying Toast message), then you can try using `getActivity()` instead of `getContext().`

Comment: It's neither, I'm calling BlankFragment.ShowMessage(getContext(), new String(body)); from a static java class implementing RabbitMQ default consumer.